# How to check dictionary's values in response

Tags: python, api, testing, pytest, assert

I'm trying to find the better way to check the values of dictionary.

I've made a pytest test, in which I send a request to API with some payload and the response looks something like this:

```
{'user': '1', 'objects': [{'id': '1', 'event': [{'type': 'something', 'timestamp': '1522991335319'}]}], 'reached': True}
```

The Key values user, id, type и reached should be the same with, values I've sent in request, and I don't care about the value of timestamp key.

When I make assert directly, it's not very convenient, for example, assertion of key "type" looks not compact:

```
assert response["objects"][0]["event"][0]["type"] == "something"
```

So, what is the better way to check the values and make the code more compact?

Comment: You could extract intermediate names, e.g. `first_object = response["objects"][0]` but otherwise... that's how.

Answer (score 1):

If this is one of a kind test in a test suite then i would do something along those lines:

```
obj = response['objects'][0]
event = obj['event'][0]

assert reponse['user']     == '1'
assert response['reached'] is True
assert obj['id']           == '1'
assert event['type']       == 'something'
```

But if you have a lot of these tests i would suggest mapping a response JSON into an object and define **eq** method for this object to take into account only relevant properties so that you can compare object using == operator using assert